# Utility Application - make it so the FlipsideViewController is not destroyed

Tags: ios, iphone

I started my project with the Utility Application as my templet. This has worked for me thus far but currently i'm having an issue with that fact that the FlipsideViewController is destroyed when you go back to the MainViewController. I expect its this code:

```
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

that is causing me issues. Question, what is the easist way to modify the code so the FlipsideViewController is not destroyed? The reason is, the FlipsideViewController holds variables during runtime that disappear when the FlipsideViewController is removed. I now understand that starting with the Utility Application was the wrong choice but want to see if this can be easily modified.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I edited my post correcting the first sentence that had a none xCode templet. I'm using the Utility Application so you can see all the code I'm using by opening a project and selecting the Utility Application.

Comment: you are going the wrong way. You seem to want to store info in the viewController... view controllers are meant to be transient. nonetheless.. easiest would be to save a reference to the view controller in prepareForSegue

Comment: Thanks, I ended up saving the variables from the FlipsideViewController to the MainViewController and then sending those variables back to the FlipsideViewController when it's called. I see, and with your help, that the viewControllers are not to hold data in a persistent way.